# .Net Core 2.1 Validate a model outside of Validate(...) method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I am building an API in .NET core 2.1 and would like to validate the model before it gets updated. I have therefore decided to implement `IValidatableObject` which works very well for simple models.

However, I now want to validate the format of the request sent by the developer to me; i.e. I want my validator to not only verify the `Validate` method but to also catch `ValidationResult` objects that may have been yielded elsewhere in the object.

My classes:

```
public class Dad : IValidatableObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Kid Kid { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> UpdateProperties(JObject props)
    {
        if (props["Kid"]["Id"] == null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("The correct format to set the Kid of Dad is {\"Kid\":{\"Id\":100}}");
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Kid.Height <= 170)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Kids need to be taller than 170.")
    }
}

public class Kid
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; } = 180;
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PatchDad([FromRoute] long id, [FromBody] JObject props)
{
    Dad dad = _context.Dads.Find(id);

    dad.UpdateProperties(props);

    List<ValidationResult> Errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
    bool IsValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(dad, new ValidationContext(dad, serviceProvider: null, items: null), Errors);

    // I need the Validator to catch errors that occur in the Dad.UpdateProperties field !

    if (!IsValid)
        return BadRequestObjectResult(Errors);

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Sending the request `PUT /Dad/19` with raw data: `{"KidId":100}` should yield two errors; the first one saying that the parameter format is incorrect, the second one saying that a `Kid` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so -- if you guys come up with something better/cleaner, I'd be glad to mark it as the answer to this question, but in the meanwhile, if someone else lands on this page, I have simply implemented a dirty solution using a private list of `ValidationResult` that can be updated from anywhere:

```
public class Dad : IValidatableObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Kid Kid { get; set; }

    [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
    pricate List<ValidationResult> ValidationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    public void UpdateProperties(JObject props)
    {
        if (props["Kid"]["Id"] == null)
            ValidationResults.Add(new ValidationResult("The correct format to set the Kid of Dad is {\"Kid\":{\"Id\":100}}", new string[] { "Kid" }));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Kid.Height <= 170)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Kids need to be taller than 170.")

        if (ValidationResults.Count > 0)
                foreach (ValidationResult r in ValidationResults)
                    yield return r;
    }
}
```